Track a tennis ball moving at high speed
I am trying to track a tennis ball moving at high speed in a lawn tennis game. I am unable to figure out which approach would be best. I need to perform these detection on a jetson nano(or jetson nano orion).
I have thought of the following approach:

Using Stereo camera (placed at a specific point most likely behind one of the player to track incoming ball) for detecting ball using Computer Vision.
Using IR base Motion capture system with reflective markers (as used in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHTizZ_XcUM&t=99s)
3D LiDAR
Ultrasonic Sensor

The following are the drawbacks of these:

Stereo Camera: Requires high shutter speed camera for detecting the ball moving at high speed. This high-end camera is most likely(according to my research) not available for jetson nano or jetson nano orion.

IR Based Motion Capture: In the youtube video they were using https://www.vicon.com/hardware/cameras/vero/. Dont know if it’s available in India. Also its cost should be under 20,000 Rupees(240$).

3D LiDAR: Doubtful if it would be able to detect high speed ball.(Best contender till now)

Ultrasonic Sensor: Worst accuracy. Low cost is its only selling point.


Let me know if any other options are available.

What’s your end goal? What do you need to determine? Position, speed…? Where? What are your constraints in terms of accuracy and processing speed?

Goal: To make a robotic arm play tennis.    I need to determine accurate position of ball so that the robotic arm can hit it accurately at the right time. The speed must be real-time.

You should probably look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plUktbRLfQw I think it's unlikely you'll get any sort of precision from stereo cameras behind the player, you probably need them on the side (and probably on top) like in the darts video. "Real-time" doesn't mean much, you need to put figures on it. What is the max speed of the ball, what is the distance the ball covers? How does the arm move (XZ only?), how fast, what is its range? This will allow you to find out what kind of latency (in ms) and frequency (in Hz/fps) you need. Note that "playing tennis" is a lot more than that.

You may want to look into https://medium.com/geekculture/track-a-tennis-ball-with-computer-vision-4f8d2f9c0412

@jcaron * How about mounting the camera on the arm itself?  * Ball max speed: 150 kmph ||   Distance to cover: 20 meter || Arm movement: XYZ (3d)  || Arm Speed: Needs to be decided (Based  on available motor speed and torque)

you're asking at a wrong site ... this site is for questions about IoT ... more suitable site is https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions

@jsotola robotics.stackexchange.com/questions is more suitable for ROS(Robotic Operating System) based questions. I have been using it for a while. I feel IOT involves using sensors and my question is also about picking correct sensor for my use-case.

I am not sure why no one has suggested OpenCV using multiple cameras. That said, the obvious hurdle here is the power and size of this robot. To make something that can return a tennis ball regardless of angle and speed will require powerful actuators. Then, to move such a machine across half a tennis court in 2 dimensions of freedom ... even more powerful motors.  There's a reason most similar robots play table tennis instead.

Consider using OpenCV and cameras to track tennis balls using computer vision. This github.com project can find tennis balls. For tacking tennis balls this may be a better example to follow.
The computer language Python is often used for quick implementation of applications. And many aspects of Python are written in the computer language C for speed. As Python is 100s if not more times slower than C. If speed it important consider writing your entire OpenCV in a faster language such as C or C++.

The ball detecting repo seems good, also I can use multiple cameras to estimate exact position of ball in a 3D space(using stereo vision) but the issue here is that I need to track fast moving ball and for this I need camera with fast shutter speed which according to my research is not available for jetson nano or jetson nano orion. The raspberry pi camera has a shutter speed of 1/5s and i need something around 1/2000s or 1/1000s at least for the camera to be able to capture the ball clearly otherwise the ball will appear distorted and the detector wont be able to detect it.

Also I am talking about raspberry pi camera V2 because it is compatible with jetson nano and can be directly attached to the board(jetson nano). Attaching any camera through USB would use much of the computation resources on the nano which is already under load because of other tasks.

@Pratham can you show us your calculations which show why you would need such a fast shutter speed? Have you looked at the project I linked to? They used standard TV broadcast video…

@jcaron I have not done any calculations but from the tennis robot video you have shared, It is working because the camera is at some distance from the ball. That is why it is able to capture the ball clearly. This is similar to what we experience when we are in a train and looking out of window, the trees closer to the train appears to be moving fast and  the trees far from the train appears to be moving slow. I want to avoid the clutter of having to setup multiple device(Cameras) here and there. Thats why I am thinking of adding a single stereo camera of the arm itself(instead of 6 cameras.

@Pratham Still, how did you come up with the 1/2000s figure? You seem to be deciding of arbitrary restrictions without any justification. Do you think your eyes have a 2000 fps frame rate? Note also that having the camera(s) on the robot complicates things even further, as you will probably need that camera to be able to rotate in one or more directions (like your head and your eyes), or you'll nearly certainly have a FoV problem.

@jcaron I recorded a video with my phone when throwing a tennis ball and i was able to see the ball clearly in the video when the shutter speed of the camera was set to 1/2000s

@Pratham even if the ball is a "trace" you can still know where the ball was at the beginning or end of that trace. But if your phone does what you need, why don't you use that?

@jcaron That a good point. I would be able to get good detection at both the ends and can predict trajectory using that. For the phone camera, I need at least 2 of them to estimate depth. Actually I am trying to use some other sensor instead of estimating depth using camera because I need the ball location to be very accurate(which i dont feel i can get from home made stereo camera). The reason for this precise location requirement is of course to hit the ball using the arm.

@Pratham, consider several images are needed to predict where next a free falling object will appear. It then becomes apparent shutter speed is less important then frame rate. An important distinction to make. For example, a classic 35mm film camera can have a shutter speed of 1ms.  But likely will not have a frame rate shorter then 250ms.

Would be better if the whole system could be integrated into a single robot, instead of having multiple cameras all around the court. This would make it easy to adapt to different court(just move the robot no need to install other 6 cameras).

That might be impractical. Cameras closer together will not be able to derive 3D positioning as easily as those spaced well apart. Consider the 3D motion capture labs at many Universities utilize entire rooms with equally spaced cameras.
